# centering an object so vertical constraints are always even

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

I need to center a UIButton('Call') between a UIView(the dialpad) and the bottom layout guide.   The view is always align center x and align center y.

So, I'd like to have the vertical constraints between the view and the call button and the call button and the bottom layout guide always equal

The UIView ('DialPad') constraints
[image]

The UIButton ('Call') is currently constained to the bottom layout guide.  I want it to be spaced evenly between the UIView and the bottom layout guide

[image]

and the storyboard preview shows different sizes and how the Call button IS NOT centered between the UIView and the bottom layout guide.  Extremely obvious in the 4.7" layout

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried doing this at runtime also through constraints ? , the approach will be as follow :
you will have your constraints set as the current state then you need to outlet the button constraint (the one from the button to the bottom layout guide) to your viewController (you do so like you outlet any UIKit control)
and then in your viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear you can write the following code :

```
//here we get the end y point of the dial view . 
CGFloat dialPadYEndPos = self.dialPad.frame.origin.y + self.dialPad.frame.size.height; 
//here we get the space between the dial view and the bottom of the view
CGFloat spaceBetweenViews = self.view.frame.size.height - dialPadYEndPos ; 
//here we get the half of the call button height . 
CGFloat halfBtnHeight = self.Call.frame.size.height/2.0f ;
//then we set the outlet constraint . 
self.bottomConstraint.constant = (spaceBetweenViews/2.0f)-halfBtnHeight ; 
[self.view layoutIfNeeded] ;
```

i haven't tested the code but theoretically it should work .

Comment: thank, easier than trying to figure out with auto layout

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Are you want this?

i use proportional width/height for parent view.

width constraint of blue view

[image]

height constraint is same.

width and height constraint of buttons in blue view

[image]